# GPS working on all devices except for Lollipop

Tags: java, android, android-location, android-5.1.1-lollipop, android-gps

long time ago I programmed an Android application which needs to know the device's location. For the purpose of abstracting the access to the location of the device I programmed a class which manages all location related things, stores current device's location, and calls the main activity when GPS or Internet status changes in order to notify the user.

This application has kept working on all devices until I bought Samsung Galaxy A5 2016, which comes with Lollipop. It works on all Jellybean devices I have tested it on and on older Android versions, but on the A5 2016, user gets notified of GPS status changes but the method onLocationChanged() must not be working because the location stored on this class is always null. Why this class for getting location has been working on all devices and now on Lollipop it stops working? Is really frustrating. Android applications are supposed to be forward-compatible.
Here is the code of the class that manages location and that has stopped working on Lollipop. Before of Lollipop, location used to be stored on the instance attributes of the class which are of type `Location`, but starting on Lollipop, the location does not get stored any longer.

```
package bembibre.personlocator.logic.locationservices;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.GpsStatus;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.location.LocationProvider;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import bembibre.personlocator.activities.MainActivity;
import bembibre.personlocator.logic.Action;
import bembibre.personlocator.logic.internet.InternetManager;

/**
 * Clase singleton que permite averiguar la localización del usuario en cada
 * momento.
 * 
 * @author misines
 *
 */
public class MyLocationManager {

    /**
     * Única instancia que puede existir de este objeto (es un singleton).
     */
    private static MyLocationManager instance = new MyLocationManager();

    private static int GPS_INTERVAL = 3000;

    /**
     * Actividad que llama a este objeto y que necesita conocer la localización
     * del usuario.
     */
    private MainActivity activity;

    /**
     * Objeto de Android que permite acceder a la localización del usuario.
     */
    private LocationManager locationManager;

    /**
     * Objeto que se encarga de escuchar cambios de localización basada en red.
     */
    private LocationListener networkLocationListener;

    /**
     * Objeto que se encarga de escuchar cambios de localización basada en GPS.
     */
    private LocationListener gpsLocationListener;

    private int networkStatus = LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE;

    private int gpsStatus = LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE;

    private EnumGpsStatuses status = EnumGpsStatuses.BAD;

    /**
     * Este atributo contiene la última localización del usuario determinada
     * por red (no muy exacta) o <code>null</code> si no se ha podido
     * determinar (por ejemplo porque no hay Internet).
     */
    private Location networkLocation;

    /**
     * Este atributo contiene la última localización del usuario determinada
     * por GPS (es más exacta que por red) o <code>null</code> si no se ha
     * podido determinar (por ejemplo porque no está activado el GPS).
     */
    private Location gpsLocation;
    private Long gpsLastLocationMillis;

    private boolean networkProviderEnabled = false;



    public static MyLocationManager getInstance() {
        return MyLocationManager.instance;
    }

    private void setNetworkLocation(Location location) {
        this.networkLocation = location;
    }

    private void setGpsLocation(Location location) {
        this.gpsLocation = location;
    }

    /**
     * Método que es llamado cuando el estado de alguno de los proveedores de
     * localización de los que depende esta clase ha cambiado de estado.
     */
    private void onStatusChanged() {
        switch(this.gpsStatus) {
        case LocationProvider.AVAILABLE:
            this.status = EnumGpsStatuses.GOOD;
            break;
        case LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE:
        case LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
        default:
            switch(this.networkStatus) {
            case LocationProvider.AVAILABLE:
                this.status = EnumGpsStatuses.SO_SO;
                break;
            case LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE:
            case LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
            default:
                this.status = EnumGpsStatuses.BAD;
            }
        }

        if (this.activity != null) {
            this.activity.onGpsStatusChanged(this.status);
        }
    }

    private void setNetworkStatus(int status) {
        this.networkStatus = status;
        this.onStatusChanged();
    }

    private void setGpsStatus(int status) {
        this.gpsStatus = status;
        this.onStatusChanged();
    }

    private class MyGPSListener implements GpsStatus.Listener {
        public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {
            boolean isGPSFix;
            switch (event) {
                case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS:
                    if (MyLocationManager.this.gpsLastLocationMillis != null) {
                        isGPSFix = (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - MyLocationManager.this.gpsLastLocationMillis) < 3 * MyLocationManager.GPS_INTERVAL;
                    } else {
                        isGPSFix = false;
                    }

                    if (isGPSFix) { // A fix has been acquired.
                        MyLocationManager.this.setGpsStatus(LocationProvider.AVAILABLE);
                    } else { // The fix has been lost.
                        MyLocationManager.this.setGpsStatus(LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE);
                    }

                    break;
                case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX:
                    // Do something.
                    MyLocationManager.this.setGpsStatus(LocationProvider.AVAILABLE);

                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Inicializa este objeto para que empiece a funcionar y trate de
     * determinar la localización del dispositivo. Además inicializa al
     * <code>InternetManager</code>, de modo que una vez que se haya llamado a
     * este método, InternetManager estará disponible en todo momento para ver
     * si la conexión a Internet funciona o hacer pruebas a dicha conexión.
     * 
     * @param activity
     */
    public void start(final MainActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;

        // Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
        this.locationManager = (LocationManager) this.activity.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Define a listener that responds to location updates
        this.networkLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                // Called when a new location is found by the network location
                // provider.
                MyLocationManager.this.setNetworkLocation(location);
                MyLocationManager.this.networkProviderEnabled = true;
                InternetManager.getInstance().makeInternetTest(activity);
            }

            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                MyLocationManager.this.setNetworkStatus(status);
            }

            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                MyLocationManager.this.networkProviderEnabled = true;
                InternetManager.getInstance().makeInternetTest(activity);
            }

            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                MyLocationManager.this.networkProviderEnabled = false;
                MyLocationManager.this.setNetworkStatus(LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE);
            }
        };

        this.gpsLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                // Called when a new location is found by the network location
                // provider.
                MyLocationManager.this.setGpsLocation(location);
                MyLocationManager.this.gpsLastLocationMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                //MyLocationManager.this.setGpsStatus(LocationProvider.AVAILABLE);
            }

            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                MyLocationManager.this.setGpsStatus(status);
            }

            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                MyLocationManager.this.setGpsStatus(LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE);
            }
        };

        // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location
        // updates
        try {
            this.locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 3000, 0, this.networkLocationListener
            );

            this.locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, GPS_INTERVAL, 0, this.gpsLocationListener
            );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        this.locationManager.addGpsStatusListener(new MyGPSListener());



        /*
         * Hay que inicializar al InternetManager y decirle que avise a este
         * objeto cada vez que el Internet vuelva o se pierda. Para ello usamos
         * dos objetos Action.
         */
        Action action1 = new Action() {

            @Override
            public void execute(String string) {
                MyLocationManager.getInstance().internetHasBeenRecovered();
            }

        };
        Action action2 = new Action() {

            @Override
            public void execute(String string) {
                MyLocationManager.getInstance().internetHasBeenLost();
            }

        };
        InternetManager.getInstance().initialize(activity, action1, action2);
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (this.locationManager != null) {
            if (this.networkLocationListener != null) {
                this.locationManager.removeUpdates(this.networkLocationListener);
            }
            if (this.gpsLocationListener != null) {
                this.locationManager.removeUpdates(this.gpsLocationListener);
            }
        }

        this.activity = null;
    }

    /**
     * Devuelve la última localización conocida basada en red o
     * <code>null</code> si no hay.
     * 
     * @return la última localización conocida basada en red o
     * <code>null</code> si no hay.
     */
    public Location getNetworkLocation() {
        Location result;

        if (this.networkLocation == null) {
            result = this.gpsLocation;
        } else {
            result = this.networkLocation;
        }

        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Si el gps está disponible y tenemos una posición guaradada basada en GPS
     * entonces la devuelve. En caso contrario intenta devolver la última
     * localización basada en red, y si tampoco está disponible, devuelve
     * <code>null</code>.
     * 
     * @return la localización más precisa que esté disponible en este momento.
     */
    public Location getFinestLocationAvailable() {
        Location result;

        switch(this.gpsStatus) {
        case LocationProvider.AVAILABLE:
            if (this.gpsLocation == null) {
                result = this.networkLocation;
            } else {
                result = this.gpsLocation;
            }
        case LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
        case LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE:
        default:
            result = this.networkLocation;
        }

        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Devuelve el estado actual del GPS.
     * 
     * @return el estado actual del GPS.
     */
    public EnumGpsStatuses getStatus() {
        return this.status;
    }

    /**
     * Método al que tenemos que llamar siempre que nos enteremos de que
     * tenemos Internet, para que se sepa que la localización por red funciona.
     */
    public void internetHasBeenRecovered() {
        if (this.networkProviderEnabled) {
            this.setNetworkStatus(LocationProvider.AVAILABLE);
        } else {
            this.setNetworkStatus(LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE);
        }
        this.onStatusChanged();
    }

    /**
     * Método al que tenemos que llamar siempre que nos enteremos de que la
     * conexión a Internet se ha perdido, para que este objeto se dé cuenta de
     * que el servicio de localización por red ya no funciona.
     */
    public void internetHasBeenLost() {
        this.setNetworkStatus(LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE);
        this.onStatusChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code:

```
public class MyLocationService extends Service{

    Location mLastLocation;
    android.location.LocationListener mLocationListener;
    LocationManager locationManager;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        // Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Define a listener that responds to location updates
        mLocationListener = new android.location.LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                // Called when a new location is found by the gps location provider.

                mLastLocation = location; // this is the object you need to play with Location changes

                // do stuffs here you want after location changes
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        };

        String locationProvider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER; // here, you can also set Network provider as per your need

        // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
        try{
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationProvider, 5000, 0, mLocationListener);
            mLastLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationProvider);
        } catch (SecurityException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

And the Manifest permission required you already know:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

And finally your service should get declared in Manifest as follows:

```
<service android:name=".service.MyLocationService" />
```

You'll have to start your service from Activity or Application class.

Comment: Thank you, but I need to know, what is the difference between your code and the mine and why the mine does not work only on Lollipop? I think my code is similar as yours and that my onLocationChanged() method is not getting called. I don't need to create a service because the user only wants to know location when he is using the application.

Comment: I think you are using gps provider and network provider at the same time, use gps provider only when there's an internet connectivity on your mobile otherwise use network provider. Try to use `if(){} else{} ` in your `try{}` block. Happy coding :)

Comment: My application started to work again and I have not changed any code. I don't know what is happening. Perhaps my device was misconfigured? I entered location settings and there were several options there: use GPS and networks, use only GPS, use only networks... It is very strange. If I change the selected option, turn off location and then turn on, my selection isn't remembered by the device and turns back to the option that was selected before.